# Computing the Lebesgue integral of a power function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm studying a book on integration (*Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space* by Frank Jones) and am having trouble with the following problem:

Define the open set
$$
G = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 1 < x \text{ and } 0 < y < x^{-a}\}
$$
where $a$ is a real number satisfying $a > 1$. Prove that $\lambda(G) = \frac{1}{a-1}$, where $\lambda$ is defined as
\begin{multline}
\lambda(G) = \sup\{\lambda(P): P \subset G, \; \\P \text{ is a finite union of non-degenerate rectangles of the form $[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2]$ }\}
\end{multline}

My first thought was to approximate $G$ using partitions. 
I constructed the rectangles
$$
I_{kn} = \left[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}\right] \times \left[(n+1)^{-a},\left(\frac{k+1}{n-1}\right)^{-a}\right],k=2, \cdots,n^2-1
$$
and defined $P_n = \bigcup_{k=2}^{n^2-1}I_{kn}$.
Then 
$$
\lambda(P_n) = \sum_{k=2}^{n^2-1} \frac{1}{n}\left(\left(\frac{k+1}{n-1}\right)^{-a}-(n+1)^{-a}\right)
$$
However, I wasn't able to find a closed form solution to this sum (except in special cases, such as when $a$ is a positive integer). Is there a different approach I should be taking?

Comment: Does this problem come before introducing the Lebesgue integral? If not, you should express $\lambda (G)$ as the double integral $\int \limits _1 ^\infty \int \limits _0 ^{x^{-a}} 1 \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d x$.

Comment: @AlexM. Yes no integrals have been introduced yet. The only thing defined so far is the Lebesgue measure of the empty set, rectangles, and finite unions of rectangles.